Screen recording's audio stops when the launching activity stops
I am using MediaProjectionManager to record screen. I request the permission from a transparent Activity. Once I get it, I call Activity#finish() on the transparent activity so it's no longer in the way.
However, as soon as I call finish(), the audio in the saved recording stops. But if I manually swipe away the Activity in recent activities, the audio continues to work.
Is this intentional for security reasons? Do I have to let the user to dismiss the activity?
